# Is there a naming convention for user defined function type?

Tags: function, go

I want to define my own function type like so

```golang
type commandFunc func(game *game, args ...string)
```

Is there a naming convention for the type name in this case? May be I should name it "command" instead? I don't ask for recommendations (those will be opinion-based) but about the existence of explicit naming convention. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, adding the `Func` suffix to the type name is common and communicates its purpose well.

Look at the standard lib for examples:

- [`bufio.SplitFunc`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#SplitFunc)
- [`context.CancelFunc`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#CancelFunc)
- [`http.HandlerFunc`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandlerFunc)

Also note from another package, identifiers are referred to using [qualified identifiers](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Qualified_identifiers), which means the package name is used as suffix. So In some case `Func` will do when combined with the package name, such as [`expvar.Func`](https://golang.org/pkg/expvar/#Func).